# apt-get install apt-transport-https fails in Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose

I've a Docker container based on `FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.179` Image.
I `RUN` a number of commands for installing dotnet core:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.179

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install sudo  && \
    sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

Once it gets to `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` it fails and complains that:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net:80 (151.101.112.204). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (5.153.231.4). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net:80 (151.101.112.204). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (217.196.149.233). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 217.196.149.233 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any  idea why it happens?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: Yes,but we set the proxy settings in Dockerfile and I can see that 
`RUN apt-get update` command  downloads the packages:
 
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://IP:PORT"
 
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "http://IP:PORT"
 
ENV FTP_PROXY "http://IP:PORT"

Comment: What happens if you try your `RUN apt-get update && ...` on a dockerfile based on an ubuntu image (`FROM ubuntu`) ? This way we should find out if the source of the problem is your base image or your infrastructure/configuration.

Comment: it surprisingly works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this, so perhaps there's something wrong with the container's internet connection (maybe proxy issues, as Marc suggested) or the sources were currently not available when you tried to build the image.

On another subject – when I tried to reproduce this with your exact code, I faced the error:

```
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
```

Because you will also probably face this eventually, you shouldn't use `sudo` in your Dockerfile. Try something like this:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.179

USER root
RUN \
    whoami \ # This will print "root"...
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https

USER jenkins
RUN whoami # ... and this will print "jenkins"
```

Comment: Thanks bellackn. Once I removed sudo and added`--no-install-recommends` it successfully worked

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, consider [accepting this answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).